# Spring Security User, Role and Privilege Case

Tags: java, spring-security, roles, privileges

I'm having a problem figuring out the User role and privilege for my use case. I want to set the Role for the user depending on one or more parameter(s).

The structure on which the User Role should depend is like this:

1. Client account 1

   - Portfolio 1A

     - Project 1A01
     - Project 1A02
     - Project 1A03
   - Portfolio 1B

     - Project 1B01
     - Project 1B03
2. Client account 2

   - Portfolio 2A

     - Project 2A03
   - Portfolio 2B

     - Project 2B01
     - Project 2B03
   - Portfolio 2C

     - Project 2C02

The Roles that are valid are: `CLIENT_ADMIN`, `PORTFOLIO_MANAGER`, `PROJECT_MANAGER` and `PROJECT_USER`

The issue at hand,

- A user can be a `PORTFOLIO_MANAGER` on portfolio 1B and a `PROJECT_USER` on project 1B03
- The same user can also be a `CLIENT_ADMIN` on client 2, a `PROJECT_MANAGER` on project 2A03 and a `PROJECT_USER` on project 2C02

After doing some extensive research I think it is impossible to do it in the `AuthorizationFilter`. Because I can't access `PathVariable` that tells me I need to get the Role for the CLientAdmin, Portfolio or Project. Let alone access the Domain Objects.

How can I make use of the Spring Security capabilities in such a multi layered construction?